# Fragment not attached to an activity when send data from my frgament to Viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, native

I have a problem when sending data from my `fragment` to the `ViewModel` that says:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException fragment not attached to an activity, Shutting down VM , Fatal Exception

```
val viewmodel :Store1_viewmodel by activityViewModels()

private lateinit var binding: FragmentShakaStoreBinding
lateinit var dataset :MutableList<item1>
lateinit var recycler :RecyclerView
lateinit var tempdataset:MutableList<item1>
lateinit var adapter: shaka_recycler_Adapter



@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    binding = FragmentShakaStoreBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)

    recycler =binding.shakaRecycler
   // dataset=viewmodel.get()
    dataset= mutableListOf()
    val curdate =LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"))

  lifecycleScope.launch {
        val db = activity?.let { Store1_Database2.getdatabase(it?.applicationContext) }
        db?.itemdao()?.getAll()?.let { dataset.addAll(it) }
        adapter =shaka_recycler_Adapter(Shaka_Store(),dataset,Shaka_Store())
      onclick(4)
        recycler.adapter=adapter
    }
        recycler.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(
            context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
        ))
        recycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)


    return binding.root
   // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shaka__store, container, false)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_item,menu)
    var menuittem =menu!!.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchview =menuittem.actionView as SearchView
    searchview.maxWidth = Int.MAX_VALUE

    searchview.setOnQueryTextListener(object :SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(p0: String?): Boolean {
           // adapter.filter.filter(p0)
          return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(p0: String?): Boolean {

            adapter!!.filter.filter(p0)
            Log.v("worrd",p0.toString())
            return true
        }

    })

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when(item.itemId){
        R.id.add_item->{
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_shaka_Store_to_insert_item)
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}

override fun onclick(Name: Int) {
        viewmodel.setitemname(Name)
}

}
```

and this is my viewmodel code

```
val context = application

private val _clicked = MutableLiveData<Int>()
val clicked :LiveData<Int> = _clicked

fun insert (data :item1){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val db =Store1_Database2.getdatabase(context)
        db.itemdao().insert_item(data)
        Toast.makeText(context,"تم اضافة العنصر بنجاح ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

fun setitemname(name:Int){
    _clicked.value = name

}

}
```

I am using  a `coroutines` is this the reason why I can not send data from `fragment` to `viewmodel` ?

Comment: You need to use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope` instead of `lifecycleScope` if you are going to use the Activity/Context or manipulate views in a Fragment, since the Fragment's views and Activity can come and go during its life.

Comment: it still not working i have replaced the lifecyclescpoe with viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope and it gave me the same error